# pointing arrow disappears on active element

Tags: html, css

I'm building a website with arrows marking active sections when they display hidden content. I'd like to have these arrows permanent when the active section is displaying its content, but instead, its just blinking when clicking and. I have tried playing with the position, overflow, but nothing has worked.

Here is the website: http://www.palcco.com.br/ftp/bucker

The HTML:

```
<section id="about">
  <section class="container">   
   <h2>Quem Somos</h2>
   <p>Institucional: Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria...</p>     

   <section class="content_box"><a class="show_hide" href="#" rel="#conteudo_about1">
    <img src="img/icone_missao.fw.png" alt="Missão">
   </a>
    <div id="conteudo_about1" class="toggleDiv">
    <p>Institucional: Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria...</p> 
    </div>
   </section>

   <section class="content_box"><a class="show_hide" href="#" rel="#conteudo_about2">
    <img src="img/icone_visao.fw.png" alt="Visão">
   </a>
   <div id="conteudo_about2" class="toggleDiv">
    <p>Institucional: Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria...</p> 
   </div>
   </section>

   <section class="content_box"><a class="show_hide" href="#" rel="#conteudo_about3">
    <img src="img/icone_objetivo.fw.png" alt="Objetivo Empresarial">
   </a>
   <div id="conteudo_about3" class="toggleDiv">
    <p>Institucional: Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria...</p> 
    </div>
   </section>

   <section class="content_box"><a class="show_hide" href="#" rel="#conteudo_about4">
    <img src="img/icone_equipe.fw.png" alt="Equipe">
   </a>
   <div id="conteudo_about4" class="toggleDiv">
    <p>Institucional: Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria...</p> 
   </div>
   </section><!--conteudo_about-->
  </section><!--container-->
 </section><!--about-->
```

The CSS:

```
#about{
    width:100%;
    min-height:300px;
    float:left;
    background:#E5E5E5;
    margin-top:0;
} 

#about h2{
    color:#004179;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

#about p,
#conteudo_about p,
#conteudo_about2 p,
#conteudo_about3 p,
#conteudo_about4 p{
    font-size:12px;
    color:#4C4C4C;
    text-align:justify;
}

.content_box{
    width:200px;
    /*height:200px;*/
    display:block;
    float:left;
    background:#E5E5E5;
    margin-right:53px;
    position:relative;
}

.content_box:active:after{
    content:'';
    width:0;
    height:0;
    position:absolute;
    border:20px solid transparent;
    border-top-color:#fff;
    top:100%;
    left:40%;
    z-index:1;
}

.content_box:last-child{
    margin-right:0 !important;
}


#conteudo_about1, #conteudo_about2, #conteudo_about3, #conteudo_about4{
    width:960px;
    background-color: #656565;
    padding:51px 20px;
    /*margin-top:10px;
    border-bottom:5px solid #3399FF;*/
    display:none ;
    position:relative;
    left:-10%;
    top:0px;
    box-shadow:174px 0px 0px 0px #656565, -174px 0px 0px 0px #656565;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Any guidanbce will be much apreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `:active` only applies when you hold the mouse button down. If you are trying to apply an effect that works after a **full** 'click` [mousedown + mouseup] you need Javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but haven't been successful yet. I've tried a few different solutions, but none of them worked, maybe because I didn't search the correct terms or because I'm a rookie.. What would the javascript be?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this:

```
$('.classeDoBotao').click(function() {
    var target = $(this).data('target');
    if (target.is(':visible')) {
        target.slideUp('fast');
    }
    else {
        target.slideDown('fast');
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<a href class='classeDoBotao' data-target='#conteudo_about1'> ... </a>
```

And I set the position of '#conteudo_about1' to relative, but I didn't work, as changing href for data-target will not show the hidden content.